# Weather Api (OpenWeatherMap) no wind direction(deg)

Tags: openweathermap

is there anyone using OpenWeatherMap api? , just a quick question, Im using their current condition API, but it doesnt return a wind directorion(**deg**) property on this lat lang (**14.6760, 121.0437**), it does when I input a different location, does this mean the wind is going **NORTH** "N if I dont receive a deg property from OpenWeatherMap?

Edit: I just noticed, its not just on that coordinates, If the wind is only at 1.5mph, it doesnt have a direction, does this mean its automatically north?

Comment: what do you mean by merely doesnt exist?

Comment: The degrees ("deg") parameter in "wind" is missing. Only the "speed" is present.

Comment: Answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475255/i-have-wind-direction-data-coming-from-openweathermap-api-and-the-data-is-repre

Comment: I think the topic starter meant completely missing "deg" parameter of "wind" which happens occasionally.